# How can we upgrade the Cloud Composer version of our composer environment?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

We have a Cloud Composer environment running a no longer current version of Cloud Composer that we would like to upgrade. I found no documentation on how to do that. Does anyone have recommendations on how to upgrade without creating a new environment and losing the run history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only current way to update a Composer Environment is to create a new one and migrate all of the data.

[This script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/composer/tools/copy_environment.py) should useful for recreating the Environments and maintain your DAG run history and settings:

> Script to create a copy of an existing Cloud Composer Environment.
>   Creates a clone of a Composer Environment, copying Environment
>   Configurations, DAGs/data/plugins/logs, and DAG run history. This
>   script can be useful when migrating to new Cloud Composer releases.

Comment: Thanks. We tried that, but it seems that the copies created by the script are the same version as the old environment. So the script does not help to update the environment.

Comment: That's odd, Are you sure about that? I have just tried and the new_copy environment 
 is in the latest composer version. The thing is that you cannot set the Composer version when creating an environment, so it will get the latest version possible. That would be weird if you are getting a new composer environment created with an oldest Composer version. 
What is your old environment version?

Comment: After your comment, we tried again with the most recent version of the script. It worked this time.